# How to print in one line the outputs of two lists?

Tags: python

I have two lists A: contains number from 1 to 10, and B contains percentage values.
I'd like to print them in this way

> 1: 10%, 2: 40%, 3: 50%

I managed to write only one array but I can't find a way to write both of them.

```
print(' : '.join(str(x) for x in A))
```

I tested zip but it printed only the first value of A and the rest of B

```
print(''.join(str(x) + " : " + str(y) for x, y in zip(A, B)))
```

> 0 : 2821 : 3422 : 2963 : 3024 : 3155 : 2496 : 3067 : 3198 : 2729 : 317

Any idea how to implement it without using for loop ?

Comment: post your input lists

Comment: You should explain why "zip didn't work"

Comment: @yatu if "ip didn't work" then this wouldn't work either - and it would loose the ordering too.

Comment: Why was this questioned reopened? despite zip not working, it was still the correct duplicate.

Comment: [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807)

Comment: @Sayse because until we know how `zip()` "didn't work", just stating that "zip is the solution" is a bit assuming.

Comment: @Sayse but given the  low quality "answers" that keep on piling, I shouldn't have reopened it obviously #facepalm

Comment: @Feras [mcve] please - there's obviously something wrong with your "lists". And once the real issue will be fixed your question should be closed as duplicate indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
spam = [1, 2, 3]
eggs = [10, 20, 30]
print(', '.join(f'{n}:{prct}%' for n, prct in zip(spam, eggs)))
```

if the first list has just numbers it can be even just

```
eggs = [10, 20, 30]
print(', '.join(f'{n}:{prct}%' for n, prct in enumerate(eggs, start=1)))
```

Comment: The op stated "zip didn't work", so until we know what he meant by "didn't work", telling him to use "zip" is not going to help...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, well, it's clear "didn't work" is "i didn't know how to use it right", as evident from his now edited question....

Comment: @buran exactly you are right. I think bruno desthuilliers should calm down a little.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```py
A = range(1, 11)
B = [10, 40, 50, 30, 70, 20, 45, 80, 20, 35]

print(', '.join(['{}: {}%'.format(n, p) for n, p in zip(A, B)]))

# 1: 10%, 2: 40%, 3: 50%, 4: 30%, 5: 70%, 6: 20%, 7: 45%, 8: 80%, 9: 20%, 10: 35%
```

Comment: The op stated "zip didn't work", so until we know what he meant by "didn't work", telling him to use "zip" is not going to help...

Comment: tbh from the edit it seems that there was only a missing space

Answer (score 0):

you can just do it like:

```
idx = [1, 2, 3]
percent = [10,40,50]

print(', '.join(f'{idx[i]}:{percent[i]}%' for i in range(len(idx))))
```

output:

```
1:10%, 2:40%, 3:50%
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a for loop:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3] # percentage values

for i, j in zip(a, b):
    print(f'{i}:{j:.0%}', end =', ')
```

output:

```
1:10%, 2:20%, 3:30%,
```

Answer (score 0):

You were doing correctly with the help of `zip`, Try the below code where I have made little changes in your code:-

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [10,40,50]
print(', '.join(str(x) + " : " + str(y)+'%' for x, y in zip(a, b)))
```

**Output**

```
1 : 10%, 2 : 40%, 3 : 50%
```

Answer (score -1):

Let,
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
print(*a,*b)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for that, i think i didn't read the query properly.Thanks for telling me.